# Qt virtual keyboard with no mouse or touchscreen

Tags: c++, linux, qt, button, virtual-keyboard

I'm working on a set of network setting pages for use on a handheld remote control system for autonomous boats.  The system has a screen(no touch input) and three buttons on each side of the screen.  I'm able to select the SSID from a list using QNetworkConfigurationManager, but I'm looking for a reasonably clean way to input the key.  The Qt virtual keyboard looks nice, but I'm not sure how I would move over the characters as well as indicate which character the user is currently resting on.  I'm somewhat new to C++ and Qt, so simpler explanations would be better for me. :)

Any ideas or suggestions would be great.  If there's a better option than the virtual keyboard, I'd love to know.

I've thought of just cycling through ASCII characters and having a button dedicated to switching which subset of characters that are being cycled through (i.e. capital, lower-case, numbers, special chars...) That seems clunky, though, and the special characters are littered through the ASCII table, so it would be a little weird to cycle through them, I think.

Thanks